# netezza nzload similar function to isnumeric?

Tags: netezza

I have data from a flat file that I am loading into netezza via `nzload`.

Some of the field types are numeric however, the data received can sometimes contain invalid characters.

How can i check to make sure that the data `isnumeric` in my import?

I saw `try_cast` for T-Sql but didn't see anything similar in netezza.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Netezza doesn't have an equivalent to `try-cast`, you can however test if the value is numeric a few different ways.  If you have the `SQL Extensions Toolkit` installed you can use a regex function.

```
 sql_functions.admin.regexp_like(<Column Name>, '^[+-]?[0-9]*[.]?[0-9]*$')
```

Otherwise you can use the `translate` function.

```
translate(<Column Name>,'0123456789','') in ('','.','-','-.')
```