# Type casting in Netezza

Tags: casting, netezza

Basically, I have Netezza at source as well as Target. In source every column is defined as NVARCHAR.

While loading the data through Informatica(ETL), we have to make different type conversions such as:

- NVARCHAR -> Timestamp
- NVARCHAR -> BYTEINT/SMALLINT/INT/BIGINT
- NVARCHAR -> NUMERIC(18,0),NVARCHAR -> Float

...and so on.

We are not allowed to drop any records, so if any conversion fails we need to put a NULL for that particular conversion. Few functions available in Informatica cannot be pushed to Netezza as we have to use PUSHDOWN Optimization in Informatica. So we are trying to write views in database and perform all the type conversions in the views.

We are having difficult with exceptions when we try to test an NVARCHAR value to see if it will fit in the target type using CASE and CAST.

```
ERROR:  pg_atoi: error in "p": can't parse "p"
```

Comment: I have proposed an edit to your question to include the specific test case you had mentioned in the other question. It will take a bit for that to show up.  In the meantime see if my answer here helps.

Comment: For "expecting a quick reply" and then also not responding to a helpful answer, I have downvoted, with regret.

Answer (score 1):

There are two primary issues that come into play here.

The first is finding a function that will comprehensively determine if the value in your NVARCHAR column actually represents a number.  The second is making sure the THEN element of the CASE statement doesn't evaluate when it doesn't need to.

As you've noticed, the built-in TRANSLATE function can do a decent job, but it's not foolproof. As far as I know, there's no built-in function that can reliably perform this check.

However, there are two included UDFs that will do a good job of this task. Both of these function must be explicitly enabled by your administrator.

- isnumber , included with the INZA functions
- regexp_like , included with the SQL Extension Toolkit

Here are examples using both, showing a cast to SMALLINT. In each I put the test CASE in a subselect to ensure that the final CAST isn't insulated from the original value.  You might think you can code this only in two nested CASEs, but with UDFs you can't always rely on that behavior.

isnumber sample:

```
SELECT ORIG_COL,
   CASE
      WHEN COL1 BETWEEN -32678 AND 32767
      THEN COL1::SMALLINT
      ELSE NULL
   END THE_NUMBER
FROM (
      SELECT 
        COL1 ORIG_COL,
         CASE
            WHEN isnumber(COL1)
            THEN COL1
            ELSE NULL
         END COL1
      FROM test_cast
   )
   t1;

 ORIG_COL | THE_NUMBER
----------+------------
 NAN      |
 1        |          1
 -+9,9.09 |
 99999    |
(4 rows)
```

regexp_like sample, using the pattern offered by @Niederee in his answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31546472/netezza-nzload-similar-function-to-isnumeric).

```
SELECT ORIG_COL,
          CASE
             WHEN COL1 BETWEEN -32678 AND 32767
             THEN COL1::SMALLINT
             ELSE NULL
          END THE_NUMBER
       FROM (
             SELECT COL1 ORIG_COL,
                CASE
                   WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(COL1, '^[+-]?[0-9]*[.]?[0-9]*$')
                   THEN COL1
                   ELSE NULL
                END COL1
             FROM test_cast
          )
              t1;
     ORIG_COL | THE_NUMBER
    ----------+------------
     99999    |
     NAN      |
     1        |          1
     -+9,9.09 |
    (4 rows)
```

Keep in mind that you will need your administrator to make either of these functions available to you.

The isnumber function comes from the INZA install, and if INZA is in place, can be loaded like so:

```
[nz@netezza ~]$ cd /nz/extensions/nz/nzlua/examples/
[nz@netezza examples]$ ../bin/nzl -d testdb isnumber.nzl

Compiling: isnumber.nzl
####################################################################
UdxName      =  isnumber
UdxType      =  UDF
Arguments    =  VARCHAR(ANY)
Result       =  BOOL
Dependencies =  INZA.INZA.LIBNZLUA_3_2_0
NZUDXCOMPILE OPTIONS: (--replbyval --nullcall --unfenced --mem 2m)
CREATE FUNCTION
[nz@netezza examples]$
```

The SQL Extension toolkit installation procedure is pretty well documented, and the regexp_like function is included with it.